# StartService takes a very long time on startup

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

I have a windows service S1 with dependency X. The service is automatic and it starts without any problems.

This service starts another service S2 with same dependency X.
The problem is that when I call StartService() to start S2, I don't return from the function for about a minute, and only than I start the entrance code of S2.

I am trying to understand why it takes so long to start the service, but I'm really out of ideas :-( .

Does anyone have any ideas ???

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe X is busy and cannot give it's status back to the system to know whether it's running or not.

Comment: Is it necessary to wait for S2 to start?  If not just start it in a thread.  Can you debug S2?  If so I would suggest doing that.

Comment: @RedX - S1 and S2 share the same dependencies, so I would suggest that if S2 has a problem to start, why would S1 has a problem to start?

@Cole, it is important for S2 to start. I can debug it, but I see that S2's main is being called about a minute after calling StartService(S2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When do you start the other service S2?  You cannot call [StartService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() until your service has reported a successful start.  Is S2 a dependency of S1?  If so, just mark it as such and let SCM worry about it.